# What is more efficient (performance-wise), a hard-coded animation or an animated video file?

Tags: ios, swift, performance, animation, core-animation

I am making an iOS game where users can acquire various in-game items to help them progress. These items are different models of servers (the game is computer-themed), and I was hoping to have a simple animated illustration of each server that a user can purchase. I was thinking something along the lines of [this image hosted on Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/5122311-Server).

For an animation such as this, what would be more efficient (performance-wise):

1. Embed static images and then code the animation part myself
2. Embed an entire animated video (like a .gif or some other video file format).

FYI, the animated illustrations will be approximately 100px by 100px, and about 3-4 of them will be showing at once.

Comment: It depends upon what you mean by “performance-wise”. Are you talking about just the rendering, or are you including the network impact, too? Pre-rendered videos are likely to be much larger. That having been said, that animation is complicated enough, that it might be complicated to programmatically generate them in a flexible manner, especially if you already have desktop tools to generate the animations easily.

Comment: By the way, you say 100×100px, but I assume you mean points, not pixels... On a 2× or 3× device, you might want the asset to be 200×200px and 300×300px, respectively, so they don’t look blurry.

Comment: Yes correct, thank you. And I'm talking about rendering. Would a few 100x100pt animation videos be able to display smoothly?

Comment: In the video production world, pre-rendered videos are always more performant than just-in-time rendering/animation. That having been said (and coming back to iOS, specifically), `AVPlayer` has a lot more overhead than the average `UIView`/`CALayer` hierarchy, and I really don’t know how well it will handle having multiple going on at the same time. If no one else volunteers practical experience, you might just want to try it yourself, create four small videos and see how well your minimally capable target device handles it.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea. I looked into animation more, and I've discovered that the common practice seems to be JSON Lottie files (which are very lightweight), so that animations can be created in animation applications like Adobe After Effects, exported into JSON, then rendered in UIView's when needed.

Comment: Yeah, if you can render that animation in Lottie, then, by all means, try that...